# Relationships between words in sentences

Tags: python, word2vec, semantics, cosine-similarity

I have two sentences:

```
sent1="This work has been completed by Christopher Pan".
sent2="This job has been finished by Mark Spencer".
```

I calculated the similarity off sentences using Word2vec:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

def avg_sentence_vector(words, model, num_features, index2word_set):
    featureVec = np.zeros((num_features,), dtype="float32")
    nwords = 0

    for word in words:
        if word in index2word_set:
            nwords = nwords+1
            featureVec = np.add(featureVec, model[word])

    if nwords>0:
        featureVec = np.divide(featureVec, nwords)
    return featureVec
```

as follows:

```
sent1_avg_vector = avg_sentence_vector(sent1.split(), model=word2vec_model, num_features=100)
sent2_avg_vector = avg_sentence_vector(sent2.split(), model=word2vec_model, num_features=100)

sen1_sen2_similarity =  cosine_similarity(sent1_avg_vector, sent2_avg_vector)
```

I would like to know how I can build a semantic tree which can tell me that:

- `completed` and `finished` are similar words;
- `work` and `job` are similar words too;
- then if I find `work/job` in the sentence or `finished/completed`, these words are both connected with `Christopher` and `Mark`.

I do not know technically if there is something in Python that can allow me to get such results.  I would appreciate if you could guide me into the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the average of all the word-vectors of words in a text is a quick & simple technique for creating a summary vector of the full text – but won't capture all the shades of meaning, especially those created by grammatical constructions, word-modifiers, or multiword-phrases.

Your word2vec model is likely to already reflect the fact that `'completed'` and `'finished'` are similar in meaning, or `'work'` and `'job'`, by making their vectors similar. Simply comparing those word-vectors directly, and contrasting the result against comparisons with other word-vectors, will tell you relatively more- or less- similar word pairs or groups.

It's not clear what you mean by "these words are both connected with `Christopher` or `Mark`". A generic set of word-vectors might not have very meaningful vectors for `'Christopher'` or `'Mark'`, as those are proper names with only local meaning, to denote a particular person, without strong associations with larger concepts. (As many word2vec training sets case-flatten words before training, it's possible there won't even be any vector for `'Christopher'`, capitalized, at all.)

You'd need to say a lot more about what you mean to achieve to know what to recommend. For example, you might need a tool for 'named-entity recognition' ('NER') to identify that `'Christopher Pan'` and `'Mark Spencer'` are discrete entities of interest, and other grammar-aware parsing or part-of-speech tagging to label them as entities related to some other verb/action.

Answer (score 1):

what you could do is create a similarity matrix between words

```
            word1   word2   word3   word4
    word1   0       1.1     2.2     3.3
    word2   1.1     0       2.2     3.3
    word3   1.1     2.2     0       3.3 
    word4   1.1     2.2     3.3     0
```

numbers for demonstration only

this can be done by two for loops

```
    for w1 in words:
        for w2 in words:
            matrix.append(similarety(w1,w2))
```

then iterate for each list of the matrix to retrieve the max value index using

```
    matrix[0].index(max(matrix[0]))
```

for instance, word 1 would return the max index of 3 for the value 3.3, therefore, word1 is mostly similar to word4